# Write a Python list in a column

Tags: python, list

How can I write a Python list in a column instead in a row? This is obviously possible, since when one calls the comamnd dir() of a variable e.g., that returns a list in column.

```
>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>> dir(a)
Out[94]: 
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__iadd__',
 '__imul__',
 '__init__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__reversed__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'append',
 ...]
```

Comment: ipython display `dir()` output as a column. standard python interactive session doesn't

Comment: Consider the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module.

Comment: what do you mean by "write"?  write to a file?  or print to the screen?

Comment: I don't mean to print it in a column format, but rather save the list actually in the form. It seems it's only an effect resulted from ipython. How can I show other lists in ipython also as a column then? such as a normal list     a = [1, 2, 3]

Comment: The pprint module does more or less what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [Join](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function to create a string out of the list. The `\n` is used to add a new line character, thus making it print in a column format.

```
list  = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print('\n'.join(list))
```